# javax.ws.rs package

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am learning RESTful Web Services and all the tutorials use `javax.ws.rs.*` package. But with JDK 6 and JDK 7, my Eclipse doesn't seem to recognize `javax.ws` package. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have jsr311-api.jar in your classpath?

Comment: Adding jsr311-api.jar fixed the issue. But the java 6 API mentions these classes. Not sure why I need to add it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[javax.ws.rs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html) is not a JDK package; it is a server-side API that forms part of the Java EE specification. You would need to include a Java EE runtime on your classpath or source an implementation from a 3rd party if you're going the [self-assembly](https://cwiki.apache.org/WINK/jax-rs-getting-started.html) route (e.g. using Tomcat.)

Comment: Why is jax-ws (Soap based) shipped with JDK but not jax-rs (Rest based)?

Comment: @Abidi I guess it is because it is much easier to write a REST client than a SOAP client but I can't give a definitive answer.

Comment: Interesting, jax-rs does come with Metro stack and Metro is shipped with JDK6. This means not full stack of Metro is shipped with JDK. Confused!

Comment: @Abidi I do not think [Metro](https://metro.java.net/discover/faq.html#components) is a JAX-RS implementation. I believe [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) is the JAX-RS reference implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You're may be missing [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) installation, or something in your environment configuration. Try also installing [Eclipse WPT](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/). You can follow this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html#installation), it covers prerequisites and basic installation procedures as well.

Comment: I added jersey installation to classpath. But Jersey does not have javax.ws.rs package. shouldn't javax.ws.rs package be in Java 6 SDK? But it doesn't seem to be.