# How to deploy a JAX-RS application on a Java SE environment?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-rs

I want to code a RESTful web service with JAX-RS, and I want publish it on localhost like `http://localhost:[port]`. I read the following in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38778695/1426227):

> The Java SE 7 (JSR 336) and the Java SE 8 (JSR 337) specifications
>   don't incorporate the JAX-RS component. However, JAX-RS applications
>   can be published in Java SE environments (using `RuntimeDelegate`) and
>   JAX-RS implementations also may support publication via JAX-WS.

The `RuntimeDelegate` is mentioned. How can I use it? If there are good examples on how to achieve it task, please share them with me.

Comment: I would like not to use tomcat glassfish and other... only ednpoint

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To deploy a JAX-RS application in a Java SE environment, you could use [`RuntimeDelegate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.html) and a HTTP server supported by your JAX-RS implementation. A servlet container is not required.

The [JSR 339](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf) states the following:

> In a Java SE environment a configured instance of an endpoint class can be obtained using the `createEndpoint` method of `RuntimeDelegate`. The application supplies an instance of `Application` and the type of endpoint required. An implementation MAY support zero or more endpoint types of any desired type.
>
> How the resulting endpoint class instance is used to publish the application is outside the scope of this specification.

Jersey, the JAX-RS reference implementation, supports a [range of HTTP servers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.javase) which you can use to deploy JAX-RS applications in Java SE.

For example, with [Grizzly](https://grizzly.java.net/httpserverframework.html) and [`RuntimeDelegate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.html), you can have the following:

```java
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig();
        resourceConfig.register(GreetingsResource.class);

        HttpHandler handler = RuntimeDelegate.getInstance()
                .createEndpoint(resourceConfig, HttpHandler.class);

        HttpServer server = HttpServer.createSimpleServer(null, 8080);
        server.getServerConfiguration().addHttpHandler(handler);

        try {
            server.start();
            System.out.println("Press any key to stop the server...");
            System.in.read();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    @Path("/greetings")
    public static class GreetingsResource {

        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
        public String getGreeting(){
            return "Hello from the other side.";
        }
    }
}
```

The application will be available at `http://localhost:8080/greetings`.

The following dependencies are required for the example shown above:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.grizzly</groupId>
    <artifactId>grizzly-http-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.30</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Other supported implementations include:

- [JDK HTTP Server](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.http.jdk)
- [Simple Server](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.http.simple)
- [Jetty HTTP Server](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.http.jetty)
- [Netty HTTP Server](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.http.netty)

[Jersey documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.javase) also describes other deployment alternatives for a Java SE environment without [`RuntimeDelegate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.html).