# Is a RESTful web server in JavaCE

Tags: java, rest, netbeans

I'm trying to find a tutorial about how to create a RESTful web server in Java (with NetBeans) but most of the tutorials I find advertise for JavaEE.

My question is therefor: Is it possible to create a RESTful web server in the CE version of Java or do I need EE?

And while on the subject:
Do you know any good video/blog/book tutorials about creating your first REST server with good background explaination and step-by-step walktrhough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Restful web service using java and spring boot and Maven build tool which will download all the dependencies from maven repositories.The final result wull be a jar file which will have embeded tomcat engine. So you don't need to worry to setup web server. Just run the jar file and rest service will be up. Thanks

Comment: Ok, thanks. What do you think is the best way for learning all of this? I'd like to get both theory and practice in order to learn it all form beginner to expert.

Comment: I would suggest picking a simple project, like a Beer Catalogue or a flight search tool and start coding.  Post on StackOverflow with questions when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

[JAX-RS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services) specification (which is describe how to create REST services) actually is part of JavaEE (from some version). But it doesn't mean you need JavaEE to create REST service.

There are a lot of implementations of jax-rs like [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/), [RestEasy](https://resteasy.github.io/), [ApacheCXF](http://cxf.apache.org/), etc.. You can run applications within a container, using WAR packaging, or using embedded servers like [Grizzly](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/basic_grizzly_jersey/jersey-grizzly-json-service.html)

Also you can create Rest using Spring, but it is not Jax-rs implementation, but just alternative.

You can find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43278950/how-to-deploy-a-jax-rs-application-on-a-java-se-environment) useful.